# pymongo cursor 'touch' to avoid timeout

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I need to fetch a large number (e.g. 100 million) of documents from a mongo (v3.2.10) collection (using Pymongo 3.3.0) and iterate over them. The iteration will take several days, and I often run into an exception due to a timed out cursor.

In my case I need to sleep for unpredictable amounts of time as I iterate. So for example I might need to:
- fetch 10 documents
- sleep for 1 seconds
- fetch 1000 documents
- sleep for 4 hours
- fetch 1 document
etc

I know I can:

- disable timeouts entirely, but I'd like to avoid that if possible since it's nice to have the cursors cleaned up for me if my code stops functioning entirely
- decrease my cursor's batch_size but this won't help if e.g. I need to sleep for 4 hours as in the example above

It seems like a nice solution would be a way to 'touch' the cursor to keep it alive. So for example I'd break up a long sleep into shorter intervals and touch the cursor between each interval.

I didn't see a way to do this via pymongo, but I'm wondering if anyone knows for sure whether it's possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For sure, it is not possible, what you want is feature [SERVER-6036](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6036), which is unimplemented.

For such a long-running task I recommend a query on an indexed field. E.g. if your documents all have a timestamp "ts":

```
documents = list(collection.find().sort('ts').limit(1000))
for doc in documents:
    # ... process doc ...

while True:
    ids = set(doc['_id'] for doc in documents)
    cursor = collection.find({'ts': {'$gte': documents[-1]['ts']}})
    documents = list(cursor.limit(1000).sort('ts'))
    if not documents:
        break  # All done.
    for doc in documents:
        # Avoid overlaps
        if doc['_id'] not in ids:
            # ... process doc ...
```

This code iterates the cursor completely, so it doesn't time out, then processes 1000 documents, then repeats for the next 1000.

Second idea: configure your server with [a very long cursor timeout](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/parameters/#param.cursorTimeoutMillis):

```
mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=21600000  # 6 hrs
```

Third idea: you can be more certain, though *not* completely certain, that you'll close a non-timeout cursor by using it in a `with` statement:

```
cursor = collection.find(..., no_cursor_timeout=True)
with cursor:
    # PyMongo will try to kill cursor on server
    # if you leave this block.
    for doc in cursor:
        # do stuff....
```

Comment: Yes that pattern is useful when possible, but in my case I have some pretty complex queries and I don't want to restart with a fresh query every time - I'd like to keep a single cursor open on the server somehow

Comment: I've updated my answer. You asked "if anyone knows for sure whether it's possible" and I've answered definitively. =)

Comment: Your answer is indeed complete so I'm accepting it. I think I just have a stack overflow pet peeve because every time I ask a focused question "how do I do X" I invariably get a million angry responses saying "you don't want to do X you should do Y or Z" when of course Y or Z are not possible in my case but it would take way too much context to explain that :). Anyway thank you for the answer it is indeed quite helpful!

Comment: I understand your peeve, thanks for accepting my answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

For me not even `no_cursor_timeout=True` worked, so I created a function that saves the data from the cursor in a temporary file and than yields the documents back to the caller from the file.

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import pickle
import os

def safely_read_from_cursor(cursor):
    # save data in a local file
    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pickle', prefix='data_', delete=False) as data_file, cursor:
        for count, doc in enumerate(cursor, 1):
            pickle.dump(doc, data_file)

    # open file again and iterate over data
    with open(data_file.name, mode="rb") as data_file:
        for _ in range(count):
            yield pickle.load(data_file)

    # remove temporary file
    os.remove(data_file.name)
```